# Mudar número de colunas no slider carouFredSel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde,
estou com uma dificuldade no seguinte site: https://totall.agenciaklik.com.br

Temos que fazer com que o slider de logo de clientes fique com duas colunas no mobile e no desktop 4 colunas.

Estamos usando o carouFredSel 6.2.1.

Parece que a lib foi descontinuada, então estamos sem referências.

Comment: Como esta o codigo da implementação? Edite a pergunta

Comment: Seria bom você indicar onde é inicializado o plugin, as opções etc.. Fuçar o códig-fonte do seu site pra achar isso é um trabalho complicado.

Comment: Está no caminho: https://totall.agenciaklik.com.br/js/main.js